# Consume WCF .svc WebService in Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, wcf, web-services

I am new to WebServices.
I have created a .NET WebService (WCF service .svc).

I am able to consume this service from a .NET Client application. Here I have added the service via (Add Service Reference) in the .NET Client.

Now I want to consume the .NET service from a Java desktop application.

- How do I add the service reference?
- How do I consume the service in java?

Answer (score 2):

You can use wsdl2java and pass it the wsdl file and it will automatically generate the whole client so you can communicate with the WebService.

If you are using eclipse you can use this plugin:

[wsdl2java eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/)

Comment: I believe in order to get this to work, you also need to make sure you're exposing an endpoint of the service over BasicHttpBinding, the only binding allowed in a non-.NET client.

Comment: @ Joe Enos: I will try this way. Is there any other way without eclipse or netbeans to do this?

Comment: @sathish yes there is just download the wsdl2java by itself and you can use it right away.

Answer (score 0):

If this code will work in production, you may also consider [REST WCF](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rest%20wcf), which will work with any language that is able to make HTTP request.